# Nginx with HTTPS upstream fails with error

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy, https

nginx works with HTTP upstream, but when I change the proxy_pass to HTTPS it fails after few seconds with the following error:

```
root@websrv1:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend" in /etc/nginx/sites-
enabled/preprod-ssl.conf:30
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Nginx config:

```
    proxy_ssl_verify       off;
    proxy_pass https://backend;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/trusted-ssl/nginx.crt;
}

upstream backend {

    server IP:PORT;
    server IP:PORT;
}
```

Comment: Please don't write "solved" in the question, instead accept your answer below. It's the only way to mark it as "solved" in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGINX with proxy_pass to https requires DNS access. Enabling DNS at the firewall solved the issue.

Comment: Why would it require that, if `upstream backend` is specified as `server IP:PORT;`, without using DNS hostnames?

Comment: not sure. without access to dns the above error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [proxy_ssl](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl):

> Enables the SSL/TLS protocol for connections to a proxied server.

Comment: I tried with the same results, found out it's because the firewall blocked connections to the internet, now trying to enable only DNS at the firewall level, will update.